# PTR record and A record should match. What if there is no A record?

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6

If I understand [RFC1912](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt) section 2.1 correctly, these rules apply for PTR records:

1) Every working IP should have a PTR record

2) PTR and A records should match (although this is not checked usually)

Now, what if I have a working IP (in my case, IPv6) and want to set the correct PTR record (which is something my ISP is able to do), but the IP does *not* have any A or AAAA record? It is just a client connected to the Internet without its own domain, not a server (but it is *not* behind any NAT, I'm talking about IPv6 here)

It has a working IP, so it should have a PTR record defined (1), but what should it point to (2) ?

Comment: I would suggest that you don't take that requirement *too* literally. RFC 1912 is informational only, and that section is clearly IPv4-centric (no mention of ip6.arpa, for example). I would take the requirement for a valid `A` record to really mean a valid **address** record, since the point is pretty obviously to provide mapping in both directions. If your host in only accessible over IPv6, there is no need (and in fact is likely counterproductive) to add a random `A` record alongside the correct `AAAA` record.

Comment: I see my question was a little ambiguous: I do not have either A nor AAAA records - just a client completely without a hostname. Yet, it's still a working IP address and should have a PTR record according to the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote in a comment:

> I do not have either A nor AAAA records - just a client completely without a hostname. Yet, it's still a working IP address and should have a PTR record according to the standard.

First, note that [RFC 1912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912), "Common DNS Operational and Configuration Errors", is **informational.** That is, it provides information and guidance but *does not attempt to specify a standard or codify requirements.* Other categories of RFCs place actual requirements on how things are done; for example, you can't write a HTTP/1.1 server and then give response code 301 any meaning other than that specified in [RFC 2616 section 10.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.2); if you do, you aren't implementing HTTP/1.1 but rather something else, perhaps patterned after it.

Since RFC 1912 is about a year older than [RFC 2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119) ("Key words for use in RFCs to Indicate Requirement Levels"), we cannot take the latter to apply specifically to RFC 1912, but RFC 2119 can still provide **some degree of guidance** in how to interpret terms like "should", "must", and so on. Particularly, RFC 2119 states that we should interpret as follows:

> **MUST** This word, or the terms "REQUIRED" or "SHALL", mean that the definition is an absolute requirement of the specification.
>
> **SHOULD** This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item, but the full implications must be understood and carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

RFC 1912, section 2.1, states in part (my emphasis):

> Every Internet-reachable host **should** have a name.  The consequences of this are becoming more and more obvious.  Many services available on the Internet will not talk to you if you aren't correctly registered in the DNS.
>
> **Make sure** your PTR and A records match.  For every IP address, there **should** be a matching PTR record in the in-addr.arpa domain.  **If** a host is multi-homed, (more than one IP address) **make sure** that all IP addresses have a corresponding PTR record (not just the first one). Failure to have matching PTR and A records can cause loss of Internet services similar to not being registered in the DNS at all.  Also, PTR records **must** point back to a valid A record, not a alias defined by a CNAME.

First, the first statement is "should", which immediately implies that this is not an absolute requirement. It may be a requirement *in some specific instances,* and that is why it is mentioned, but it isn't a requirement in the general case.

I would take the second paragraph, which starts with "make sure", to place the stronger requirement on the administrator. Note that the next sentence again says *should*, not *must* or any variation thereof.

The bottom line here is two-fold:

1. If you don't have a need for a globally unique host name which maps to your IP address, there is no need to add one to DNS. (If it's a client-only system which doesn't expose any services, and which has no problems using desired services, then you obviously don't have a need for it at least for the time being.)
2. If there is no host name in DNS which maps to your IP address, there is nothing for a PTR record for your IP address to point to, and thus you aren't allowed to add or have added a PTR record for your IP address. (This follows from the requirement that a PTR record points to a host name with a corresponding address record.)

As an aside, note that in practice there need not be a one-to-one mapping between hosts, IP addresses, and DNS names. For example, I'm responsible for a server host which has three distinct IP addresses, multiple names pointing to different of those IP addresses via both direct address records and CNAMEs, but only one of those IP addresses has a proper reverse name (which has an equivalent forward mapping back to the IP address in question).

Comment: Yes, this is probably what I needed to hear. I SHOULD have a PTR record, but they all MUST point back to a valid A record. I therefore will not have any PTR record (which is allowed under certain circumstances) and all 0 of my PTR records will point to the valid A record. Fishy, but I guess that's it. Thanks :)

Comment: @KamikazeCZ Pretty much that, yes. (Except, perhaps, "all 0 of my PTR records will point to the valid A record **which doesn't exist**".) I suppose this answer is the long-winded way of saying that there is *no need to make it more complicated than it needs to be.*

Comment: The terms in RFC 2119 were not necessarily used in exactly that manner in RFCs which predated it, or even some RFCs which followed it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Did you miss the part of my answer that says: ***While it's about a year newer** than RFC 1912 and **thus not fully applicable,** we can turn to RFC 2119 for **some guidance** on how to interpret terms like "should", "must", and so on.*? In RFCs that reference 2119 for interpretation of those terms, the terms also are usually written capitalized. I don't believe that in any way invalidates my answer, however, especially since 1912 is informational.

Comment: No, I did not miss that at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Then I fail to see what you were getting at with your comment. Care to clarify?

Comment: I think the point needs to be emphasized, since you have relied on RFC 2119 too much in analyzing RFC 1912.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Fair point, there. Feel it is better now?

Answer (score 0):

There are no strict rules on which records to create. There can many A and/or AAAA records pointing to the same IP address, or there can be none. There may be a reverse (PTR) record for an address or there may not be. There is nothing valid or invalid about any of these cases as there are no real rules.

There are certain expectations however. One of them is that if you run a mail server then the IP address that the mail server uses to connect to other mail servers should have a PTR record that points to a hostname that in turn has an A or AAAA record for that IP address.

Let's look at an example:

- You mailserver has IPv4 address `192.0.2.1`
- There is a PTR record for `1.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa` pointing to blabla.example.com
- There is an A record at blabla.example.com pointing to `192.0.2.1`

That way the PTR record can be used for domain-based reputation based filtering as the holder of the domain would not have created the correct A record inside their zone if the name was fake.

Because of this verification strategy there will be less 'trust' if your PTR record doesn't match an A or AAAA record. Everybody might create PTR records pointing to `something.important.google.com` but only Google would create a matching A/AAAA record for that name if it really existed. The non-existence of the A/AAAA record doesn't prove that the address isn't from Google, but it doesn't confirm it either.

The same goes for all such records: it is good common practice to create matching A/AAAA and PTR records but it isn't a requirement. It will be mostly servers receiving mail from that IP address that will enforce matching records.

RFC1912 is an informational RFC that describes common practice, not an Internet Standard. Your PTR record can technically point anywhere you wish, but it would be bad manners if you point it at a domain name that is not yours. If you really want to have a PTR record and you don't want to create a matching A/AAAA record (can't imagine why, but ok) then point it to a non-existing name inside one of your own domains. If you don't have your own domain then you should probably ask someone who does if you can point to theirs.

Comment: According to RFC1912 section 2.1, both (1) and (2) apply, so, as I've written: it is not checked or enforced usually, but according to the RFC, PTR should be set even if there is no A record. And A and PTR should match. But what should PTR match if there is no A? I don't see this answered in your post.

Comment: Edited the answer to include the information you request!

Answer (score 0):

RFC1912 is old and informational... it never progressed to Standard so is not required to implement so nobody has bothered with it generally.  You'll find most everybody ignores that advice most of the time except for mail servers and secure FTP servers.  It also doesn't cover AAAA records.

Bottom line, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: The `AAAA` DNS RRtype wasn't specified until [RFC 3596 in October 2003](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3596#section-2.1), about six and a half year after [RFC 1912 in February 1996](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1912), so it's not surprising that RFC 1912 doesn't cover RFC 3596 material.